# Code optimization advice

Tags: wordpress, function, optimization

I was hoping that someone could look over my code here and offer any advice so I can learn if there are better ways to accomplish the same task because as I am self taught I feel I lack some of the best practices knowledge and tend to just work at it until I can make it do what I want.

Anyway, I am making a function for the wordpress attachment template that will automatically detect the rank of a military personnel member whose image is being shown in the a wordpress gallery. The intent is that someone can click on the individuals image and it will display the wordpress attachment page with a brief note about the rank and then put the rank insignia next to the image based upon the military rank listed in the image caption. The function works. I am just wanting to improve it and learn if this is the best way to accomplish this or if there are better coding practices I should be following. Thanks for the advice!

```
    <?php $a = get_the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php
if (substr_count($a, 'Gen') > 0) {
    $rankimage = 'http://myurl.com/images/Gen.png';
    $rank = 'General';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Col') > 0) {
    $rankimage = 'http://myurl.com/images/Col.png';
    $rank = 'Colonel';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'LTC') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Lieutenant Colonel';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Maj') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Major';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Cpt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Captain';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Lt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'First Lieutenant';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, '2Lt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Second Lieutenant';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'SMA') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Sergeant Major of the Army';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'CSM') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Command Sergeant Major';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'SM') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Sergeant Major';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, '1Sgt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'First Sergeant';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'MSgt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Master Sergeant';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'SFC') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Sergeant First Class';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'SSgt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Staff Sergeant';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Sgt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Sergeant';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Cpl') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Corporal';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Spc') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Specialist';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'PFC') > 0) {
    $rankimage = '';
    $rank = 'Private First Class';
}
elseif (substr_count($a, 'Pvt') > 0) {
    $rankimage = 'http://myurl.com/images/01Pvt.png';
    $rank = 'Private';
}
?>
<?php 
if ($rank != null){
    echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style='text-align: center;' colspan='2'>Rank Detected! $a is a $rank! <img src=$rankimage></td></tr>";
//I placed this if here to close the table in the event that the wordpress image had no description containing the closing tags. I nested it inside the if loop so that it doesn't have to run on pages that don't detect a rank in the image caption.
    if (get_the_content() == null){
        echo "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
    }
}
else{

}
?>
```

I added the additional code below.

```
    $date_list = Array(
    Array( 'age', "$birthday", 'now' ),
    Array( 'membership', "$datejoined", 'now' ),
    Array( 'promoted', "$lastpromo", 'now' ),
);

foreach ( $date_list as $date_set ) {
    $var = $date_set[0];
    $start = $date_set[1];
    $end  = $date_set[2];
    $datetime1 = date_create($start);
    $datetime2 = date_create($end);
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    if ( substr_count( $var, 'age' ) > 0 ){
        $age = $interval->format('%y');
    }
    elseif ( substr_count( $var, 'membership' ) > 0 ){
        $years = $interval->format('%y');
        $months = $interval->format('%m');
        $membership = floor(($years*12)+$months);
        if($membership > 1){
            $suffix = 'Months';
        }
        elseif($membership == 1){
            $suffix = 'Month';
        }
        else{
            $membership = "< 1";
            $suffix = 'Month';
        }
    }
    elseif ( substr_count( $var, 'promoted' ) > 0 ){
        $years = $interval->format('%y');
        $months = $interval->format('%m');
        $test = $interval->format('%a');
        $promoted = floor(($years*12)+$months);
        if($promoted > 1){
            $suffix = 'Months ago';
        }
        elseif($promoted == 1){
            $suffix = 'Month ago';
        }
        else{
            $promoted = "< 1";
            $suffix = 'ago';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created that code, you had to do a lot of cutting & pasting, right?  You got one if statement that worked, and then cut & pasted it, and changed the text, and kept doing that 19 times.  And boy did that suck, didn't it?

What you want to do when you are doing the same thing over and over again is do it in a loop.  In your case, you need an array of information about each of the possible ranks, and then you repeatedly do your substr check (which might not be the best way to do it, but we'll let it be for now), and then set your return variables accordingly.

```
$a = get_the_excerpt();
$rank_list = Array(
    Array( 'Gen', 'General', 'Gen.png' ),
    Array( 'Col', 'Colonel', 'Col.png' ),
    // And so on...
    Array( 'PFC', 'Private First Class', '' ),
    Array( 'Pvt', 'Private', '01Pvt.png' ),
);

foreach ( $rank_list as $rank_set ) {
    $abbr = $rank_set[0];
    if ( substr_count( $a, $abbr ) > 0 ) {
        $rank = $rank_set[1];
        $img  = $rank_set[2];
        $rankimage = ($img == '') ? '' : "http://myurl.com/images/$img";
        break; // Stop looping through the foreach loop
    }
}
```

Look back at your original code.  You're doing the exact same thing 19 different times.  You're doing the `substr_count()` check 19 times, you're setting `$rank` 19 times, and you're setting `$rankimage` 19 times.  What happens if you need to add an Admiral?  You have to cut-and-paste that same chunk of code yet again.  What if you find a bug in how you're doing `substr_count()`?  You have to change 19 lines of code, and hope that you change all 19 of them correctly.

Now, look at what I've done as your alternative.  You have one little framework of code that does what you need it to do.  If you want to change that `substr_count()` to a `preg_match()`, you only have to change one line of code instead of 19.  If you have to add an Admiral, you add one line of code to your `$rank_list` array, instead of cutting & pasting yet again.

There's a basic principle in programming called DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself.  When you find yourself cutting & pasting over and over (indeed, cutting and pasting at all) you're probably violating the DRY principle.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly the type of advice I was looking for. I have one additional question, what is the advantage of using preg_match() over substr_count()?

Comment: It's a matter of which is more appropriate for your needs.  I don't know exactly how your matching is supposed to work.  I just used that as an example.  Also, please accept the answer.

Comment: I have applied what you taught me here to several other functions I have put together. I very much appreciate the help Andy, it has been invaluable in improving my skills. 

One part I ran into problems trying to simplify the function using an Array, perhaps you can offer some additional insight. I added the code I had come up with so far to the bottom of my original question.